# Creating multiple plan subscriptions

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-craftcommerce, plugins, stripe, products

**Versions:** 
 - Craft CMS (3.1.21)
 - Craft Commerce (2.1.2)
 - Stripe for Craft Commerce (1.2.0)

**Problem:** 
- My website offers user's ability to subscribe to several subscriptions at the same time. Currently, I have created products that represent each subscription so they may be added to the cart. These products are purchased like a regular 'purchasable' element.

My plugin listens to the event **EVENT_AFTER_COMPLETE_ORDER** and finds all subscriptions that were in the completed order.
I could create each subscription individually using Craft's **createSubscription()** method found in **craft\commerce\services**, but doing so causes multiple invoices to be sent out to customers and each invoice created is also charged a fee by Stripe.

My Goal is to create one subscription that contains several subscriptions inside of it (https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/multiplan). This would only generate one invoice.

I am able to use the Stripe API to do this successfully but at the cost of bypassing Craft. Is there a way to do this through Craft so it knows about all subscriptions that have been created?